# Unobtrusive validation - how to find a dependent property for comparison

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

working on an MVC 3 app.  I have finished my custom server side code, now working on the client side.  I want to tie it in to the existing unobtrusive, so I am using the addMethod.  The pseudo goes something like, " If the radioValue is true, then the counterValue must be greater than zero."  The problem is, my function stops running at the 3rd line, when trying to get the radioValue.  It throws a generic exception "Check you method".  Please advise.  Oh, and this is my first time doing this, so if you see anything, please let me know.  Thanks!

```
$.validator.addMethod("requiredifyes", function (val, elem, param) {
var dependantProperty = param;
var radioValue = document.getElementByName(dependantProperty).value;
var counterValue = val;

if (radioValue == true) {
    if (counterValue == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("requiredifyes", "othervalue", "requiredifyes");
```

Comment: Why are you creating new variables to assign to variables that already exist?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementByName` will give you List of elements Nodes ..

SO when you you try to access the value on the list directly , will throw an error.. The elements inside the collection will have a value not the list as a whole...

If you are sure there is only one by that name .. try this

```
var radioValue = document.getElementByName(dependantProperty)[0].value;
```

If there are multiple elements with same name .. You would need to iterate over them./

Also you are unnecessarily assigning two variables when you can assign the function parameters directly..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.  I have taken out all the unneeded variables and based off Sushanth's comment regarding the code returning an array, I looked for a JQuery solution  by researching the JQuery forum.  Here is the final working code:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("requiredifyes", function (val, elem, param) {
       var radioValue = $('input:radio[name="' + param + '"]:checked').val();

    if (radioValue == "True") {
        if (val == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("requiredifyes", "othervalue", "requiredifyes");
```